# Set width of an image with a variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, width

I am creating a ranking bar chart with five iterations of the same bar image.  I want to change the width of each bar with a variable that is actually a percentage.  I can do it easily by putting each percentage as the width of each image.  Like....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="20%" >5 stars</td>
                    <td width="80%" bgcolor="#e2e2e2">
                        <img src="http://qr8.us/images/review-bar.jpg" width=80% height="10" alt=""/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td >4 stars</td>
                    <td bgcolor="#e2e2e2">
                        <img src="http://qr8.us/images/review-bar.jpg" width=14% height="10" alt=""/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td >3 stars</td>
                    <td bgcolor="#e2e2e2">
                        <img src="http://qr8.us/images/review-bar.jpg" width=3% height="10" alt=""/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td >2 stars</td>
                    <td  bgcolor="#e2e2e2">
                        <img src="http://qr8.us/images/review-bar.jpg" width=2%  height="10" alt=""/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td >1 star</td>
                    <td bgcolor="#e2e2e2">
                        <img src="http://qr8.us/images/review-bar.jpg" width=1% height="10" alt=""/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, I want to apply that width as a percentage with a variable that I am calculating elsewhere. The variables will look like ...

```
var ttlrevsprcntfive = 80;
var ttlrevsprcntfour = 14;
var ttlrevsprcntthree = 3;
var ttlrevsprcnttwo = 2;
var ttlrevsprcntone = 1;
```

I have tried everything to get the variable to work in the width attribute of each image. Big fail.

How can I assign the value of each variable to the image width? Remember it is a percentage.   Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for.
Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oscadrxa/)

```
'use-strict';
(function(){
    function resize() {
        var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for(var i=0;i<img.length;i++) {
           img[i].style.width = 20 + '%';
           img[i].style.height = 20 + '%'; 
    }
}
}());
```

As to your comment, I've made an exmaple with your html source code. See the updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oscadrxa/9/)
This should do the job. If you are satisfied please accept this solution as the right anwser and click the arrow on the left to the post.

Answer (score 0):

how exactly have you tried to apply the value?

You can achieve this e.g. by doing this:

YourImageObject.style.width = ttlrevsprcntfive + "%";

You can get YourImageObject e.g. by document.getElementsByTagName("img")[*imageIndex*] or by document.getElementById('*imageId*') or using JQuery.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I'm not sure what you mean with the last sentence. Are you using YourImageObject.style.width as a straightforward VAR?

Comment: well you can create a variable to store the result of document.getElementsByTagName('theTagName')[tagIndex] and then access its style-property. You can see an example of that it in @fubbe's post.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am having trouble relating your answer or fubbe's example to my problem. I know the answer is there but I can't see it. 

Fubbe's example includes other things that are confusing the issue for me(like buttons and resizing) 

Can you please guide me with a more complete answer with the code I have provided?

My variable is:
var ttlrevsprcntfive = 80;

I want the width of the image to be that value as a percent.
I do not understand the purpose of **YourImageObject.style.width**

Sorry, I thought this would be easier.

Comment: YourImageObject is just some random variable i took. Maybe this JavaScript-code helps you then: document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style.with = ttlrevsprcntfive + "%"; (This code sets the width of the first image-element in your html-document to the value of the variable ttlrevsprcntfive plus "%" (the value has the type String)). In case you are having trouble to understand access to HTML-Elements (Tags) in JavaScript you can read through this : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_methods.asp

Comment: Now I think we are getting to it. Your code helped. However, you say ...(This code sets the width of the first image-element in your html-document to the value of the variable ttlrevsprcntfive plus "%").  There are dozens of other images on the page.  How can I apply this to specific images?  See this fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/jdjackson7/qnpsL3n9/

Comment: Any more thoughts on how to do this? How do I apply this to specific images? See Fiddle... jsfiddle.net/jdjackson7/qnpsL3n9
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can add an id to each image like <img id="fiveStars" ... /> then set the image width via this code : document.getElementById("fiveStars").style.width = ttlrevsprcntfive + "%".

Comment: Your code was very helpful in helping me get this figured this out.  After many hours I finally realized that the **document.getElementById** code must be in the _BODY_ while all of the other js must be in the _HEAD_. Otherwise, all of the other many variables on the page were clashing with each other.  Check out the final result of this small section of a very large page. (http://www.qr8.us/images/Capture1.PNG) This little section actually has 21 different variables at play.    Thank you Hans for your help and persistence.